# Send raw POST data from one php page to another

Tags: php

Not sure my title was very descriptive of my issue. Im not terribly good with words haha.

We have a very old script that requires php 5.3.29 to function, and we just had to move to a new server where that script no longer functions. I am trying to get it to work temporarily while we re-write the entire thing in something newer.

This script is related to our software authentication, and the post that is sent to this script directly from the application is encrypted using RSA and a varying number of post elements (hundreds of them).

I would like to take that post data and relay it directly to another URL that is running a modified version of the old script on php 5.3.29 without having to loop through all the post elements. Is that possible? For instance we access the posted data using:

```
$crypted = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

But is there a way to just re-send that data as it is directly to another server from inside this php page and then return the result returned by that page?

Sorry if this is a stupid question. I am not a php programmer... but am stuck with this gig! :)

For sake of argument lets assume that https://auth.ourdomain.com/auth.php is the script the software calls with this complex POST, and https://php53.ourdomain.com/auth.php is the script we want to re-send that post to for processing (and receive just a simple string in return).

Dave

Comment: You could do `$_SESSION['post'] = $_POST;` then POST data would be accessible via that index on any page. This presumes the POST data isn't going to change....well that session index but then the same POST index it had

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This sounds like cURL might be of most help. You can GET or POST to another page this way. You can use `file_get_content()` if you like, this is basic GET request unless you work it into a POST. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You could also use curl to send get/post requests.

Comment: Going to assume this is because you can't simply edit the application and change the endpoint that it posts to? Obviously, if it's a website, you could update the form action and tell it to post to a completely different URL even if they form is being filled out from a different website.

You might also want to look into a redirect on the target page. You can forward POST data on using Apache's redirect or similar if that's what you have access to.

Otherwise, curl might be the best way as people say.
Curl lets you pass in the params as array, i.e $_POST is the array.